# No me permite ejecutar la consulta Select

Tags: java, web, hibernate

Estoy intentado lanzar una consulta `Select` de tipo `inner join` a lo cual necesito convertir en leguaje hql Hibernate.

```
String hql = "SELECT Negocio.NombreNegocio,Negocio.Telefono,Negocio.Direccion FROM Ingrediente \n" +
    "INNER JOIN Negocio on(Negocio.IdNegocio=Ingrediente.IdNegocio)\n" +
    "INNER JOIN Receta on(Receta.IdReceta=Ingrediente.IdReceta) \n" +
    "INNER JOIN Usuario on(Usuario.IdUsuario=Receta.IdUsuario)WHERE Usuario.IdUsuario="+IdUsuario;
```

Comment: Podrias agregar que tipo de error te da o alguna informacion mas?

Comment: No me sale ningun error,no me aparece nada porque no esta tomando la consulta, probe la cosulta select inner join en mysql y funciono bien. Necesito saber como convertir esa consulta en leguaje hql

Comment: Entonces la pregunta es como transformar eso a hql, no tiene nada que ver con que se pueda ejecutar como sql? intentaste algo?

Comment: exacto si señor como transformar esa consulta a hql ,intente algunos modos y no funciono